# Ports & Databases: Designing a game server architecture for many simultaneous live multiplayer games

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket, server, database

I'm designing a framework for running synchronous multiplayer games.
A game server needs to be able to create many instances of its designated game, according to some parameters. For starters, this will just be the number of players in a given instance already.

Please check out http://agar.io/ for an example of a server that does this.

In that game, 100 players can be connected to 1 instance. When a new connection comes in, the server must decide

"assign to an existing instance" - > look that server ID up in the database -> send connection commands to the client - > client connects

OR

"create a new instance of a game" - > create new database entry for the new instance - > send connection details - > client connects & waits for additional players.

What I'm curious is how to divide port hosting & databases.

I'm considering Node.js + websockets + Mongo. Please tell me if the following sounds reasonable or not, and why:

- I create a master account database
- Players authenticate with the master database
- New databases are spun-up on a per instance basis.
  ** This makes for easier lookups & cleaner db look up code (as opposed to parsing through a mongo record of all simultaneous games with lots of writes & reads happening!)
- Players establish a websocket request with the game instance (possibly to a dedicated port, see below).
- Players exchange websocket commands which are routed through the controller actions which update the mongo database for that instance as the game is played
- Eventually one of these websocket actions triggers a game-completed state
- On game completion, save updated scores etc to the master account database. Delete the game instance database

What parts of this are badly designed?

Should I do a similar thing with port hosting eg host on port 1000, 1001, 10002 etc.. to make for faster DB look ups (each port has its own game instance server) or is the speed bonus negligible?

Please comment with any questions. Please at least look at agar.io to have an understanding of the kind of architecture I'm looking for